# Записать версию в переменную

Tags: java

Подскажите код, который бы получал содержимое файла (version.txt), который находится по ссылке http://localhost/version.txt и преобразовывал бы его в переменную current_version. Файл version.txt просто содержит число, например - "1.01".

Comment: Вам нужно сначала узнать ip адрес локалХоста, потом сделать GET запрос по адресу `http://{IP}/version.txt` и результат запроса и будет искомым числом, после приведения его из строки в `Double` методом `Double#parseDouble(String string)`

Comment: Покажите, что вы уже сделали

Comment: @ЮрийСПб localhost, как пример. Можете кодом написать пример?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman я написал уже кучу всего, все стер, ибо не работало. Я смотрел в сторону InputStream BufferReader, но наверное ошибочно. Поэтому и обратился сюда, чтобы помогли каким-никаким примером кода, если это конечно возможно.

Comment: @ДмитрийГончаров даже не правильный код лучше, чем никакого кода.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman я не думаю, что код, который не на что не наводит - это лучше, чем ничего. Было бы от чего отталкиваться - я бы обязательно приложил.

Comment: @ДмитрийГончаров вас не наводит, а других может и навести. Сейчас вот не понятно с чем у вас проблемы. Все выгляди так, что вам просто хочется, что бы за вас сделали.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman я вроде попросил пример кода, а не написать за меня приложение. Можно мне просто подсказать (ссылкой вообще идеально) куда смотреть, чтобы это сделать. Вы написали уже, наверное, больше в комментариях, чем сам код должен быть. Не тратьте свое время, если не хотите или не можете помочь. Я сказал, что потратил целый день на эту проблему, сказал в какую сторону смотрел (InputStream, BufferReader), но мне это не помогло написать нужный код, поэтому я пришел сюда за помощью, а не потому что вам делать нечего - напишите за меня программу.

Comment: @ДмитрийГончаров сделать за вас это очень просто. Я хотел же помочь вам научится делать самому.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman спасибо, но я просил помочь мне примером, а не общением со мной в комментариях. :-)
Человек пришел, нашел стандартное решение от Oracle и просто вставил сюда - помог решить мне проблему, а я теперь сижу и разбираюсь, как и что работает в примере, чтобы понимать. Разница очевидна.

Comment: он решил её за вас. для обучения - это не эффективный метод.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать проще, и стандартными средствами (пример от [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)):

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://localhost/version.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

String inputLine;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    sb.append(inputLine);
in.close();

String result = sb.toString();
```

Теперь в `result` будет весь ваш файл, записанный в `String`.
В android работать это не будет, и тогда используйте асинхронный пример, приведенный в другом ответе.

Comment: Кажется это именно то, что мне было нужно. Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно взять либу `OkHttp` и сделать как-то так:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

String url = "https://{IP}/version.txt";

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse");
        Log.d(TAG, "response.code(): " + response.code());
        String res = response.body().string();
        Log.d(TAG, "response.body().string(): " + res);
        double version = Double.parseDouble(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: А без подключения сторонних библиотек этого сделать нельзя? Стандартными средствами так сказать.

Comment: Можно, конечно, но мало кто так делает. По крайней мере я ни разу за много лет не пробовали даже так делать. Получается уж очень много некрасивого и лишнего кода

Comment: @ДмитрийГончаров можно без библиотек. Все нужное есть в стандартной библиотеки.